# How to verify asp.net mvc web API is utilizing SSL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a asp.net mvc web api project. I am passing sensitive data to a web api application. The web api application I created requires ssl. When I call the web api using https I would like to verify that the information is encrypted from end to end. Is there a way to do this or am I just being paranoid.

Comment: You want to verify if incoming request is over HTTPS ( [HttpRequset.IsSecureConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) ) or you want to understand what HTTPS/SSL means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure IIS to require SSL (and IIS will perform redirections on your behalf) but the main way is by doing this:

```
if( Request.IsSecureConnection ) {
    // Using SSL or TLS.
}
```

Comment: You can also decorate controllers and/or actions with `[RequireHttps]` and http requests will automatically be redirected to https before being allowed to execute the controller/action.